# GetUser returns null for other GuildUsers, but returns fine when I have my GuildUser

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I am making a discord bot in discord.net, and I'm attempting to make commands, but I can only get my OWN user for `context.Guild.GetUser()`, others return null

`IUser GuildUser = context.Guild.GetUser(userID); Console.WriteLine(GuildUser.Username);`

I tried inputting other IDs of my guild members straight into `GetUser()`, still seem to return null, I also turned on Intents on the Discord Dev Portal, I expected it to grab the user, it only seemed to grab mine

Comment: You need to enable Guild Members intent and set AlwaysDownloadUsers to True

Comment: `AlwaysDownloadUsers` is a property in the `DiscordSocketConfig`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I actually forgot to put AlwaysDownloadUsers = true

```
DiscordSocketConfig config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
  LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
  AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
  MessageCacheSize = 100,
  GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All
};

_DiscordClient = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
```

thanks Anu6is